# How to increment number of fields in php using javascript or jquery or ajax without reload whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a form in yii and there is a text field named certificate_name in it.
Now i want that when I click on the plus icon, the text field should increment by one and appear below the previous field.

Here is my php code:

```
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= $_REQUEST['total_certi']; $i++) { ?>
        <div class="pr-ser">

            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model4, 'certificate_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model4, 'certificate_name', array('maxlength' => 300)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model4, 'certificate_name'); ?>
            </div><!-- row -->

        </div>
    <?php } ?>

            <p id="demo"></p>
            <div class="row buttonsub">
                <input type="button" id ="trainer_certi" onclick="myFunction()" value="Add" />
            </div>
```

There is no issue if I increment the whole div instead of a fild. I can manage this. My JavaScript code is as below:

```
   <script>
      function myFunction() {

         var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('demo').value, 10);
            value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
            value++;
        document.getElementById('demo').value = value;
        var total_certi = value;  
        alert(total_certi);
        }
    </script>
```

If I get the result in `$_REQUEST['total_certi']` and if it works in for loop then I complete my work.

Here I can get incremented value in alert in script but how to apply this value to php and increment the number of field without reloading page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using ajax request but for multi text fields you need to write/array `certificate_name[]` instead of `certificate_name`.

here is working & simple codes for you -

Add More Button -

```
<a class="btn btn-primary add-more" href="#">Add More</a>
```

Add More Field JS Code -

```
   $('.add-more').live('click', function(){
      var url_path = ''; //your project base url 
            $.ajax({
                url:url_path+'?r=ajax/addmore',
                data:'req=add_more',
                dataType:'html',
                type:'POST',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success:function(resp){
                    $('.pr-ser').append('<div class="row">'+resp+'</div>');
                },
                error:function(er){
                    alert("An error has occured, Please reload/refresh the page and try again.");
                }
            });

       return false;
   });
```

Write code into your Ajax Controller -

```
public function actionAddmore(){
   if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
       $cert_name = CHtml::textField('certificate_name[]', '', array('maxlength'=>'300'));
       echo $cert_name
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , by little modification i did it as per my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yii2 - have a look at following extension: [Yii2 Dynamicform](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform). I've used it in my project and it does exactly that you are trying to build.

Comment: yes i looked it, seems very good but i am very close to the result so if possible i go on my way because i am new in YII. otherwise i go with your suggestion.